# Can I run a subset of pure Java code from an Android project via a regular Java main method?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have some code in an Android project that [parses HTML using Jsoup.](http://jsoup.org/) It doesn't use anything Android specific, they're just static methods that take an InputStream, and return my model classes. The app uses Gradle to build itself in Android Studio.

Is there any way I can create a standard Java `main` method to do something like load HTML from a local file, run it through my parser, and output a JSON file (using Gson on my model class)? I'm thinking maybe I can add a new `sourceSet` to Gradle like a `jvmCompatible` set of classes? I would greatly prefer not to copy my code to a separate project.

EDIT:
I guess I didn't make this clear, but I would like the be able to run this locally on my dev machine from the command line, rather than on an Android device or emulator.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is--why would you want to do that as a `main` method and not as a standard utility class?

Comment: Your question is not clear but as far as I understood your question, here you can run the java code in an Asynctask and get the output json file and then you can update the ui.

Comment: @DaveNewton, does my edit make things clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to do anything in the build file to set this up; the build file generates Java .class files, and you can feed them to Java directly from the command line. You can add a `main` method to any class:

```
package com.example.foo;

class MyClass {
    ...
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `main` method will be happily ignored util you invoke it via the Java command line. You can do this by setting your classpath to the intermediate build directory and telling the Java command line which class to start:

```
java -classpath app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/ com.example.foo.MyClass
```

where you pass in the path to the `build/intermediates/classes/debug` directory in your app module's build output, and the fully-qualified name of the class.

Note that if you're running a release build that uses ProGuard, this main method could get stripped out if it's not otherwise referenced in the code.

Make sure you don't access any Android classes or you'll get a runtime error.

As an aside, you might find it worthwhile to separate out your Java-only code into a Java-only module in the build. Among other things, it would let you use JUnit to write nice test cases for the classes within; if you're asking this question because you want to do some testing of your parser, you might find it convenient to do so within the auspices of a unit test.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's exactly what I wanted. I do have unit tests that run on the emulator, this is more for ad hoc stuff I do during development to be able to get code running quickly.